# Ruby Error Help, Enumerator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some code that worked locally but when it ran RSPEC on the server I had a build fail.

Here is my code:

```
def sort_software_list(software_list)
  pkgs = JSON.load(File.read("#{Rails.root}/lib/tasks/pkgs.json"))
  hash = pkgs.map { |e| e["name"] }.each_with_index.to_h
  sorted_list = software_list.sort_by { |e| hash[e.name]}
  sorted_list
end
```

It takes a file in the Rails project which is just a json file. The function takes in software_list and sorts it with the correct order that the json file is in.

So my error on the failing rspec is:

```
undefined method `to_h' for #<Enumerator:0x0000000db66b30>
```

I am having trouble thinking of a reason this is happening. Like I said it is working locally as far as I can tell. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm willing to bet that your local machine has Ruby 2.1.0 or greater and your server has a lesser version. Enumerator didn't get a `to_h` method (via Enumerable) until Ruby 2.1.0. An easy workaround is to use the `Hash.[]` method instead, after converting the Enumerator to an Array:

```
hash = Hash[ pkgs.map {|e| e["name"] }.each_with_index.to_a ]
```

You may also find it useful to manage your project's Ruby version with rbenv or RVM to ensure that you're using the same version in development and in production.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My first thought was to stub the file, which I am trying to do now. If that doesn't work I will try your way.